# how to add custom button on highstock/highcharts on subplot/addAxis

Tags: button, highcharts

in highstock..specifically on volume and price chart combination. how can i add "button" on top of Volume chart..i am trying to create similar to link below.. where there is a close (X) button right most corner

http://finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=IBM+Interactive#symbol=ibm;range=1y;compare=;indicator=bollinger+volume+macd+rsi;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;

Comment: Just add html button which will have binded click event which will destroy chart. To destroy chart use `chart.destroy()`, see [reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.destroy()).

Comment: but i dont want to add on top of the chart.i want to add it jus above the volume like shown in yahoo chart... (above the subplot.) i cant find a way to add that

Comment: As Pawel mentioned, you need to destroy chart and create new with one yAxis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add buttons when using exporting module (if you don't need to, disable it), for example: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/2F4pJ/

```
exporting: { 
    buttons: {
        customButton: {
            x: -62,
            onclick: function () {
               alert('Clicked');
            },
            symbol: 'circle'
        }
    }
}
```

But still I don't see difference between positioning HTML button with left/top and position: absolute, or adding built-in button from Highcharts, where you need to use x and y to position button.

Comment: but if you see above example.. there are 'close' button on top of every chart (like above additional y-axis).. how can i add multiple above each additional Y-Axis..

Comment: Calculate position according to axis height? Add event to close that pane and that's it? You should be aware that's not something built-in for Highcharts, you need to do on your own.

Comment: i know how to add buttons

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's possible, it's just not documented. Highcharts' SVG renderer has a "button" Method which looks like this:

```
button: function (text, x, y, callback, normalState, hoverState, pressedState, disabledState, shape)
```

Meaning you can create a button like this:

```
chart.renderer.button('Click me', 150, 25, myCallback)
```

Comment: Note that you also need to manually add the button object using the 'add' function. This would create and show the button:

chart.renderer.button('Click me', 150, 25, myCallback).add()

Answer (score 0):

> you can add buttons using exporting module (if you don't need to, ignore it), for example: [jsfiddle url (you can check here)](https://jsfiddle.net/Anjani001/rhqaL26f/11/)

```
exporting: {
 buttons: {
  customButton: {
    x: -350,
    y: 40,
    onclick: function() {
      alert('Clicked');
    },
    text: "button1"
  },
  custoButton: {
    x: -275,
    y: 40,
    onclick: function() {
      alert('Clicked');
    },
    text: "button2"
  },

  cusoButton: {
    x: -200,
    y: 40,
    onclick: function() {
      alert('Clicked');
    },
    text: "button3"
  },
}}
```